# macOS PowerShell Connect-PnPOnline fails due to advapi32.dll?

Tags: macos, powershell, sharepoint, advapi32

When I try to run the following command:

`PS /Users/<user>> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site>`

I get this error:

`Connect-PnPOnline: Unable to load shared library 'Advapi32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libAdvapi32.dll, 1): image not found`

What is "Advapi32.dll", and how can I resolve this?

**My environment:**
macOS 10.15.3
PowerShell 7.0.0, installed using homebrew ([as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7#installation-of-latest-stable-release-via-homebrew-on-macos-1012-or-higher))
SharepointPnpPowerShellOnline, installed like this: `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`.

Comment: I don't think the dependent Sharepoint libraries are available for .NET Core yet. `Advapi32.dll` is a core Windows API, I believe. There is an issue on GitHub for this [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/869).

Answer (score 1):

Workaround here is to use tbe device login approach, which would be

```
Connect-PnPOnline -PnPO365ManagementShell
```

And it worked like a charm for me.

This approach would ask you to use a browser to enter the code and authenticate in the browser.

Helpful context and source: https://www.erwinmcm.com/cross-platform-pnp-powershell/